# Operation not permitted with my personal Documents Folder using the Terminal App

Tags: terminal, big-sur

I just updated my system to 11.5.2 (20G95).

After the reboot, suddenly, using Terminal, I can not access my personal Documents Folder anymore.

I am able to `cd` into my Documents Folder but I am not able to `ls`.  I am receiving an **Operation not permitted** warning message when I try for example to `ls`.

```
my_username@my_computername Documents % ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

Using the Terminal App, I can access without any issue other personal Folders such as Desktop, Downloads, etc. but the issue is with my Documents folder.

I can access without any issue using the Finder Application but the problem is with the Terminal Application that I can not access the Documents Folder.

```
drwx------@  5 my_username  staff   160B Aug 31 17:21 Desktop
drwx------@ 17 my_username  staff   544B Sep  1 13:29 Documents
drwx------+  4 my_username  staff   128B Aug 28 06:46 Downloads
```

Everything was working fine before I updated the system.

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to grant Terminal permission to access `Documents` in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders. Alternatively, you can give Terminal Full Disk Access in the same pref pane.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have no idea why it was deselected but I did what you said and now it is fixed.  Thanks a lot